# How to make a prototype cell 'disappear' when it is 'empty' (not clickable)

Tags: swift, uitableview, parse-platform, cell

I am making an application where the user can see certain items/users within his x km radius (much like Tinder where you can set the radius of girls/guys you want to see in your area). So in my `cellForRowAtIndexPath` function I am determining whether a cell can be shown.

If he is in the radius, the event is shown. If the location is too far away, it shouldn't be using a cell.

My current code just hides the cell, but it is still clickable. I want it to NOT use a cell in the first place, but I couldn't find how to do it. Any ideas?

```
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath, object: PFObject?) -> AllGeneralMeetsTableViewCell {
        //get location from backend
        let locLati = object?["coordLat"] as? Double
        let locLongi = object?["coordLong"] as? Double

        let currentLocation:CLLocation = CLLocation(latitude: localLati , longitude: localLongi)
        let meetLocation:CLLocation = CLLocation(latitude: locLati! , longitude: locLongi!)
        let meters:CLLocationDistance = currentLocation.distanceFromLocation(meetLocation)
        // make distance in km
        let distInKm = meters/1000
        //get distance that user has set in his settings
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("GeneralMeetsIdentifier") as! AllGeneralMeetsTableViewCell!
        if (distInKm <= settingsKm) {
        // Extract values from the PFObject to display in the table cel
            if let title = object?["title"] as? String {
                cell?.titleCell?.text = title
            }
            if let message = object?["message"] as? String {
                cell?.messageCell?.text = message
            }
            if let image = object?["image"] as? PFFile {
                image.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock({ (imageData: NSData?,error: NSError?) -> Void in
                    if (error == nil) {
                        let image1 = UIImage(data:imageData!)
                        cell.imageCell.image = image1
                    }
                })

            }

            return cell
        }
        else {
        return cell
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

The data is being returned by the following query

```
override func queryForTable() -> PFQuery {
    let query = PFQuery(className: self.parseClassName!)
    let FBID = myUser.objectForKey("facebookID")!
    query.whereKey("facebookID", equalTo: FBID)
    query.whereKey("private", equalTo: "false")
    return query
}
```

Comment: Why don't you just filter out all items you don't want to display before calling tableView.reloadData()?

Comment: Because i don't really know how. All items are given back from the Parse backend with the queryForTable (see code above). Should i filter there, or in what part exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your cellForRowAtIndexPath-

```
if cell is to be displayed {
    tableView.rowHeight = 120
    //Replace 120 with desired rowHeight
} else {
    tableView.rowHeight = 0
}
```

Hope this helps :-)

Comment: Thanks, this helped me the fastest

Answer (score 1):

You want to make the cell disappear when there is no data. If I am right, then you can use this library called as '[DZNEmptyDataSet](https://github.com/dzenbot/DZNEmptyDataSet)' to display some images telling the user that there is no data to load. Use Cocoapods to install it, or just drag the files and create a bridging header. The usage is pretty straightforward as well - just follow the documentation at the GitHub.

Comment: Hey, this is not really what I want, since there is some data that appears (if (distInKm <= settingsKm)) which is shown, but the data that returns false is now also returned in an empty cell. I need those empty cells to be gone (like numberofRowsInSection should be correct). Still thanks for the info, i might use this when no info at all is shown.

Comment: Hey I guess I have found you a solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31619134/how-do-i-remove-empty-cells-in-table-view-ios-swift 
let me know, if this doesn't work, I will figure out some other way.

Comment: I've checked the answer out before as well, but it didn't help me. Isn't there some kind of method where you can return nil instead of the return AllGeneralMeetsTableViewCell()?

Comment: No, but we can try doing something, know which cells are going to be empty and give them a height of 1px or less.

Comment: I've tried to be more clear about the problem (added screenshot + some extra code). I also changed the `return AllGeneralMeetsTableViewCell()` to just `return cell` so that is shows the prototype cell which isn't filled in, because the location for that cell is too far away (so it shouldn't be shown).

Comment: Let me try this out.

Answer (score 0):

Parse provides a type [PFGeopoint](https://parse.com/docs/ios/guide#geopoints) and it is even supported in the Query, with Parse framework you can also obtain location the same way you download stuff from database, this way you can download only those posts that are available for the user in his range...

`PFGeoPoint.geoPointForCurrentLocationInBackground { (geoPoint: PFGeoPoint?, error: NSError?) -> Void in 
    if error == nil { //asynchronous, U have access to GPS location
        // create Parse Query
        let query: PFQuery = PFQuery(className: "Post")
        // 5km range 
        query.whereKey("gps", nearGeoPoint: geoPoint, withinKilometers: 5.0)
        //rest of query....
    } else { // dont have access to GPS or whatever
        print("Eror location: \(error)")
    }
}`

Comment: Could have tried this indeed, but I stored the latitude and longitude separately in the backend, not as a geoPoint. If I have to re-write some of the code, this is definitely  one of the things I will improve.

Comment: I think you should always optimize your network request, they are very expensive and if you are hiding some cells you downloaded a lot of useless crap. Creating PFGeoPoint is very easy

     `let lat = locationManager.location.coordinate.latitude`

     `let lon = locationManager.location.coordinate.longitude`

     `let myGeoPoint = PFGeoPoint(latitude: lat, longitude:lon)`

Comment: Mazel Tov I'm rewriting my code as we speak. Thanks for your input.

Comment: The code is kinda working, but also not working. The first time the query is being called, my values for the current local geopoint etc. isn't called yet from the database, so it gives back 0 for both. `myGeoPoint = PFGeoPoint(latitude: localLati, longitude: localLongi)` 
        `query.whereKey("GeoPoint", nearGeoPoint: myGeoPoint, withinKilometers: settingsKm)`

Comment: I dont know if I undestand correctly but it seems you dont understand how it works. The function `PFGeoPoint.geoPointForCurrentLocationInBackground` will get location from you device and doesnt do any network request, you still have to do the standard query network request `query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock`, try to update your question with more code if it doesnt work

Comment: not needed, I got it to work by using the queryForTable() function, and I had to use way less code, which always makes me happy :) Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The proper solution is to remove the data from your data source so that it won't be displayed in the first place. But sometimes this is a lot of work.

If you just want to hide a cell you can give it a zero height using the `tableView(_:heightForRowAtIndexPath:)` delegate method:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    if indexPath.row == 1 {
        return 0.0
    }

    return tableView.rowHeight
}
```

Comment: I went with the even easier solution, but you are right, I will implement the proper solution soon during a code review.